# Events with constant probabilities regardless of $p$ for Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\{X_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter for $0 < p < 1$. Find a single
event $A$ that has probability $1/2$ regardless of the value of $p$ and a second event $B$ that always has
probability $1/3$. Use the $\sigma - $algebra axioms to show that $A$ and $B$ are actually events.

I'm unsure how to proceed with this question.  Do I need to look at all the possible events such as the probabilities of the intersections of all the random variables?  I realized that $\frac{E[X]}{2pj}= \frac{1}{2}$ for all values of $ p $ where $j$ is the number of random variables and $X$ is the sum of the $ j $ random variables, but I'm uncertain whether this is relevant.  Any suggestions for how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a very nice question, but you're probably going to have to either provide more details or show more effort if it's not going to get closed because people think you're just trying to get them to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the problem, so just a partial intuition as opposed to the full solution would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add "Just looking for a hint or a starting direction -- I want to figure it out on my own but have no idea where to start" to the question.

Comment: BTW, I assume your "event $A$" can be different for different values of $p$, yes?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.

Comment: Maybe you can split by even/odd indices? Like the probability that $\sum_{i\,even}X_i$ is greater than $\sum_{i\,odd}X_i$ for some finite upper limit?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Treat the results of $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as the base two expansion of a number between $0$ and $1$, e.g. $$X_0 = 1, X_1 = 0, X_2 = 1 \rightarrow 0.101_2 = 1 \times \frac{1}{2} + 0 \times \frac{1}{4} + 1 \times \frac{1}{8} = \frac{5}{8}.$$

Each additional digit splits the interval $[0,1]$ into twice as many intervals, and you should be able to find a "leading segment" (i.e. an interval of form $[0,\alpha]$) where the probability of the corresponding real number falling into that segment is close to $\frac{1}{2}$. (Of course the value of $\alpha$ will depend on $p$.) As you look at more and more $X_n$ the intervals get finer, and you should be able to pick successive values of $\alpha$ so the probability gets closer and closer to $\frac{1}{2}$.

(I have left this really hand-wavy and haven't introduced any of the notation that a serious answer should have to provide so that you can figure that stuff out. Also, I'm pretty sure this would work, but I might have missed some issues with this method. Also also, this argument looks to be a bit of a pain to formalize, so if there's a slick easy answer I've certainly missed it here. Good Luck.)

---

Reply to comment:

Let's take $n=2$. The "leading segment" candidates are $[0,0/4]$, $[0,1/4]$, $[0,2/4]$, $[0,3/4]$, or $[0,4/4]$. As $i$ goes from 0 to 4,  $P(\text{mapped number lying in }[0,i/4])$ goes from 0 to 1, so at some point the probability goes from being less than 1/2 to greater than 1/2. Maybe instead of looking at a single value, we think of a "bracket" of two values, let's say it's when growing from $[0,2/4]$ to $[0,3/4]$. Now add another digit, or as you say "further expansion", we can consider $P(\text{mapped number lying in }[0,5/8])$. Depending on whether this is greater or less than 1/2 our bracket shrinks to either "between 1/2 and 5/8" or "between 5/8 and 3/4". If you've ever done a proof by bisection, or programmed a bisection search, this should look familiar.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your insights.  I'm still trying to understand the concept of finding this "leading segment."  Are you saying that I should continue looking at further expansions such as 0.1010, 0.1011, 0.10101, 0.10111, etc.?

Comment: I tried using this method to find a single event with probability 1/2.  I found this event to be the binary representation of an even number n of random variables containing an even number of 1's before the first zero.  I'd be curious if somebody could confirm this result.

Comment: In other words, the probability that the binary representation of an even number n of random variables contains an even number of 1's before the first zero is 1/2.